# Bash - file, arrays and output

Tags: bash, text-processing, files

I have a file that contains employees names, departments and the cities the employee is in, something like:

```
John
IT
Chicago
Joshua
accounting
New York
Marcy
CEO
Los Angeles
...
```

I have to transform this file to this format:

```
John?IT?Chicago
Joshua?accounting?New York
Marcy?CEO?Los Angeles
```

using the question mark as a field delimiter

I have done this bash script so far:

```
fname="mix.txt"
exec<$fname

index=0
while read line ; do
        ARRAYLINES[$index]="$line"
        index=$(($index+1))
done < $fname

NUMBERLINES=$(grep -c "" $fname)
NUMBERLOOP=$(($NUMBERLINES/3))


count=0

for i in $(eval echo {1..$NUMBERLOOP})
do
  one=$(($count+1))
  two=$(($count+2))

  LINE0=${ARRAYLINES[$count]}
  LINE1=${ARRAYLINES[$one]}
  LINE2=${ARRAYLINES[$two]}
  ((count + 3))

  FINAL="$LINE0?$LINE1?$LINE2"
  echo $FINAL >> final.txt
done
```

The final file has the correct number of lines, but all lines are equal to the first employee data, like

```
John?IT?Chicago
John?IT?Chicago
John?IT?Chicago
John?IT?Chicago
John?IT?Chicago
John?IT?Chicago
John?IT?Chicago
```

any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
(( count + 3 ))
```

you just adding 3 to $count and discarding the result. Try with

```
(( count = count + 3 ))
```

Comment: duuuuh... I knew I was missing something! Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Normally I'm not a fan of posting "actually you should do it this way" answers, but somebody [already addressed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25679/73) the error in your script and I can't stop myself -- you're making this way too hard. This is much easier with a tool like `sed` or `awk`. For example, in `sed`:

```
$ sed 'N; N; s/\n/?/g' /path/to/your/file
```

This reads three lines (one by default, the other two because of `N; N;`), and replaces newlines with question marks (`s/\n/?/g`). It will output the converted version of the file; if you want to replace the contents in-place use the `-i` flag

Comment: amazing. As I said I am a newbie in Bash. I know a lot of stuff but I am far from having a really deep knowledge. Thanks for this amazing command! I knew sed, but I was not aware it could do stuff like that in one line!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Why the address? Works for me without too.

Comment: @manatwork Oh, I suppose it would, since I'm consuming the lines immediately. Edited, thanks

Comment: anyway it is giving me an error on the tilde, saying **": invalid command code ~**

Comment: @DigitalRobot Are you on Mac OS? According to a [random blog](http://alexle.net/archives/tag/invalid-command-code), you need to use `-i ""` instead of just `-i` if so. You can also just do `sed 'N; N; s/\n/?/g' /path/to/your/file > /path/to/your/file-fixed` to create a new file instead of overwriting the existing one

Comment: what is the `/g` for ?

Comment: @HananN. Global; it replaces all occurrences instead of just the first. `echo aaa | sed 's/a/b/'` would output "baa"; `echo aaa | sed 's/a/b/g'` outputs "bbb"

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do that is with `paste`:

```
<infile paste -d '?' - - -
```

This will paste three lines at a time using the question mark as delimiter.  If speed/fast processing is what you need then this is the way to go. Also, as [*Stéphane Chazelas*' points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25678/bash-file-arrays-and-output/251689?noredirect=1#comment433702_251689), you could even edit the file in-place.

Comment: You **can** edit in-place with `<infile paste -d '?' - - - 1<> infile`.